# libGDX black screen after loading and displaying a gallery photo

Tags: android, image, libgdx

Does anyone have a good example of loading an image from the photos gallery and rendering it in libGDX?

I am trying the following, however it does not render the loaded texture (it's just black). Other textures loaded via assets are rendering just fine.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    this.activity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Then,

```
protected Texture getLibGdxTextureFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    Texture texture = new Texture(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
    Gdx.gl20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureObjectHandle());
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    Gdx.gl20.glBindTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

    return texture;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) { 
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
                try {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    Texture texture = getLibGdxTextureFromInputStream(imageStream);

                    Screen screen = game.getScreen();
                    if (screen instanceof MyGameScreen) {
                        ((MyGameScreen)screen).galleryImageSelected(texture);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Screen screen = game.getScreen();
                    if (screen instanceof MyGameScreen) {
                        ((MyGameScreen)screen).galleryImageSelected(null);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In my game screen:

```
public void galleryImageSelected(final Texture texture) {
    if (texture != null) {
        // set the background texture to the image pickers active texture
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                galleryImageTexture = texture;
            }
        });
    } else {
        // display a message e.g. "image format not supported"
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

And then I try to render in my render loop with:

```
batch.draw(galleryImageTexture, 0, 0);
```

But it doesn't render.

**UPDATE**

This just gets weirder... I've narrowed it down to a problem with setting the galleryImageTexture from the onActivityResult method.

Even if I return a hardcoded texture e.g. new Texture("test.png") from there it still does not render, whereas if I set it e.g. on load of the activity then it renders fine...

Comment: There's a decent chance you're running into the texture size limit. On some GPUs, the image dimensions cannot be bigger than 2048.

Comment: Does your android app have the appropriate permissions to access the internal storage of your device?

Comment: @B.Naeem yep, I've added the appropriate permission to read the file, and I can see that the texture data is there post load, it's just not rendering it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Interesting, I'll have a play with that tonight and get back to you - the image I was loading WAS quite large, it was a standard photo that I took on the phone (it was over 4000 pixels across).

Comment: @Tenfour04 nope, it's not that, I have tried with a 800x480 image and it's the same story :-(